# How to detect same data in a datagridview column?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vba

When a user enters data into the datagrdview, the user cannot enter data that already exists in the datagridview. If the user tries to enter the same data in the datagridview (in the same column), a message box will pop up and tell them: "cannot enter same data on datagridview."

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you using for your source for the datagridview?  Is this a Windows application formed in Visual Studio?  Are you populating an Access table?  Need more info, please.

Comment: I am using MySQL database as my data source. Yes, this is Windows Form that created through Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I didnt populate Access table.. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you bro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got the solution! This is the code I used to solve the problem. My datagridview name is DataGridView3. The code are :

Private Sub DataGridView3_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView3.CellEndEdit

```
    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows
        Try
            If DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString <> Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString AndAlso DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString = DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString Then

            ElseIf DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString = Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString Then

                If Row.Cells(0) Is DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0) Then
                Else
                    MsgBox("Can't Duplicate Condition Data!")
                    DataGridView3.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = ""
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the input against the database to see if it is already there.  For example, run the following MySQL statement to check if the input is database:

```
Dim userInput As String
userInput = TextBox1.Text 'an example of user input from a textbox
Dim MySQLStatement As String = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE your_column = '" & userInput & "';"
```

I am unable to continue the example above without knowing how you are connecting to the database, but it may be unnecessary.  However you connect, you can check the record count after you have executed the MySQL statement.  If it is 1 or more, than you know the data is already in your database and you can stop the user input from going into the database.

Comment: Actually I dont want to connect to the database first, because I want to avoid the datagridview from contain two same data. So my idea is, I want to create message box pop out to tell user that 'cannot enter same data' when the cell is end edit. Im so sorry if you cannot understand my comments.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for trying to help me. Your help are greatly appreciated.